# The difference between call a function in ng-click and call it after loading the DOM

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with AngularJS. I'd like to know if there is a difference between this :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $scope.callFunction();
});
```

and

```
<a href="#" ng-click="callFunction()"></a>
```

When you change a $scope object like this :

```
$scope.callFunction = function() {
  //change $scope objects
}
```

I am asking that because I am using steppers like this https://github.com/ipiz/md-steppers and when I change the page I have two possible behaviors. The first one is when I click on the `<a>` tag, my scope object is reinitialised. When I call the same function  I mean 'callFunction()' after loading the DOM, the scope object is not reinitialised.

Comment: What is a stepper?

Comment: Oh sorry I update my post

Comment: In both examples you are simply calling a function. The only difference I can tell from the code provided is that one is called as the result of a click, while the other is the result of the document being ready. Without a better view into your code, and where in your code each statement is placed, that's all we can tell.

Comment: `document ready` is pointless.... angular doesn't even bootstrap until the document is ready

Comment: you can use the angular.element(document).ready() method to attach callbacks for when the document is ready. and on the other hand The ngClick directive allows you to specify custom behavior when an element is clicked.so for ng-click to work you have to click the specific element with which it is associated .

Comment: OK It means that I should have the same result

Comment: No, not really. The code provided is not enough to understand or explain this issue to you in a meaningful way.

Comment: really not clear what your problem is. Provide [mcve] and a proper problem description

Answer (score 0):

This code, by itself tells us nothing about the `$scope`:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $scope.callFunction();
});
```

It's impossible to know what the expected behavior should be base on this alone. Is it in a controller? Out in the middle of nowhere? Embedded in a script tag on your home page? These are all details we need to know. There is really never a reason to use `angular.element(document).ready()` inside a controller. That just doesn't make much sense. As charlietfl says, this call is pointless. Angular does not even run until the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you could also use `ng-init()` instead of `ready`

if you would like to reinitialized your scope variable when your angular is ready, you can do it by using `ng-init()`.

The question suggests that you should go through [Angular Initialization Process](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Answer (score -1):

when you call $scope function from within JS event (like dom ready), angular is not aware of this event. To make angular aware you can wrap it whith $timeout or $scope.apply functions for example:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.callFunction();
  });
});
```

when you call your function from within angular directive like ng-click, ng-change, etc.. angular is aware of this change and function execution affects $scope immediately within current scope digest

Comment: there is no point in using ready event in the first place. This will just bloat the code needlessly. the document will long have been `ready` by the time this code runs

Comment: the question was about difference of calling $scope function from different contexts

Comment: but this context makes no sense ... fix that as problem not add hacks on top of it

Comment: angular (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js) allows to use document ready by calling bindJQuery():  //try to bind to jquery now so that one can write jqLite(document).ready()